# Serverless / AWS Lambda - Scala Example

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy with serverless a scala project on AWS lambda. I have followed the tutorial and used [this template](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/tree/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-scala-sbt). After I deploy to AWS and trying to invoke the function, I am receiving this error

```
START RequestId: e07358e6-dd11-4f58-a59e-fd080dd257c6 Version: $LATEST
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:66)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader.findInterfaceParameters(EventHandlerLoader.java:475)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader.wrapRequestHandlerClass(EventHandlerLoader.java:513)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader.loadStreamingRequestHandler(EventHandlerLoader.java:571)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader.loadEventHandler(EventHandlerLoader.java:580)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.findUserMethods(AWSLambda.java:115)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:286)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more
END RequestId: e07358e6-dd11-4f58-a59e-fd080dd257c6
REPORT RequestId: e07358e6-dd11-4f58-a59e-fd080dd257c6  Duration: 49.35 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 25 MB  
RequestId: e07358e6-dd11-4f58-a59e-fd080dd257c6 Process exited before completing request
```

I am new to serverless and I have no idea how I can address this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to deploy an assembly jar including all dependencies (w/ scala-library)

Comment: How are you deploying your serverless template (ex: using aws cli or some ide with aws toolkit installed)

Comment: Thanks guys. I was doing `sbt package` which generates a skinny jar file. I should do `sbt assembly` and then it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing `sbt package` which generates a skinny jar file. I should do `sbt assembly` and then it works for me.